# what is different in CoreData

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

I am working with coredata framework. And now I have a problem with this:
I have relation `[1:n]` between `Order` and `OrderDetail` Object.
In first tableview, I use `NSFetchedResultsController` to get list of `Order`.
My problem is **how to count `Ordertail` of each `Order`**.

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

I got `Order` object. Call it parent_Object.

What is the good way to count `OrderDetail`:

1. use `NSFetchRequest` with Predicate `"Order == %@'`, parent_Object. Then I count the array of result fetch.
2. use property: `parent_Object.OrderDetails.count`

What is the difference and which way will save the time execute.
Please help me out.

Comment: Please note: `count` is not a property, it's a method! Dot syntax does indeed work, but please stick to bracketed method calls when it's not a simple getter!

Answer (score 0):

In general, fetching from core data is expensive work. But,you should not really experience any performance issues in either cases. To answer your question, you should use the property because there is no need for fetching or predicates. A predicate is used only when you filter certain objects out. So what you are doing in the two methods is

1. Creating a predicate and using that to fetch all `Order` objects in an array. Then, you call count on it to get the total number of `OrderDetails` for an `Order`.
2. You already have an nsset of managed objects and call count on it.

So, logically the second way is faster as you don't do any fetch. But it really should not matter for small projects. If you have large number of objects and you just want to sample the results, you could always call `setFetchLimit:` on the request before you fetch it.

Comment: if use setFetchLimit:, how can you get exactly number of orderdetail??

Comment: you can't get the number. I just mentioned setFetchLimit: as a method that could be of use in a different scenario where you are worried about efficiency. you should use parent_Object.OrderDetails.count

Answer (score 0):

If you will look what apple does when you ask

```
    [paretnt_Object.orderdetails allObjects];
```

You will find that they do a simple FetchRequest.

I think you have 2 options

1. use -

   ```
   - (NSUInteger)countForFetchRequest:(NSFetchRequest *)request error:(NSError **)error
   ```

   this method will return **only the count** of the object that you will get if you will use the use fetch request. I believe it is faster as it does not load the objects.
2. In the last WWDC there is a lecture on CoreData. one of the things I learned from the lecture is that you should try to build your data in the way that you are going to use it later. If your Know that you are going to need those fetch requests very often, you might consider storing the  **OrderDetail count** as property inside **Order** and update the count every time it changes. this way you will do it once every time you add or subtract an OrderDetail, and it will be much faster when you will do it to many Order entities at once.

GOOD LUCK

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But if compare of your 1st method with count on NSSet, what is good way?

Comment: Do you have the set fetched already? were do you get the NSSet from? To me the second method will be the best is you are ding it often. else use the first one.